# Weird laptop battery behaviour

Tags: linux, power-supply, battery-life

On my 4 year-old laptop, the battery discharge pattern is weird. It goes does relatively quickly and steadily down to 6%, then remains at 6% for 1.5 hrs and then very quickly goes down 1%/min.
[image]

I had a similar issue with my previous laptop too and never found a proper solution to calibrate the battery properly. If I connect the charger before the charge gets really low, calibration goes haywire.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can try to reset the battery by: 1) complete discharge, 2) wait at least 3 hours (for the battery to cool down) 3) connect charger and let charge fully, then leave connected for another few hours.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "weird", it happens quite often with older batteries.